# Chart.js Tooltip Trigger Issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In my implementation of Chart.js (v3.9.1) I have a line graph with tooltips. The tooltip plugin definition is as follows ( `...` added for brevity in code):

```
this.graph = new Chart(document.querySelector('#m-graph'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {...},
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        interaction: {
            mode: 'point'
        },
        stacked: false,
        showTooltips: true,
        title: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: scales,
        plugins: {
            legend: {...},
            tooltip: {
                position: 'nearest',
                callbacks: {
                    label: (context) => {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I hover over data points, the more "to the right" I go on the X axis, the further away from each data point I need to hover to get the tooltip to popup. GIF below shows issue.

[image]

Any ideas/advice on what settings to toggle to fix this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a css issue to me. Like if you would scale the canvas using CSS and it caused the graph to stretch.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, hmmm, let me look into that potentially being the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Konrad Linkowski above for pushing me into the right direction. I had the `canvas` element for the graph sized with `width: calc(100% - 5rem)`. Removing that fixes the issue.